# Howto limit the width of a span?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I wonder if it is possible to give a span a maximum width.
I tried using the following css

```
display: block;
max-width: 300px;
```

But the width gets ignored when the text content of the SPAN doesn't fit into the span.

I would like to cut the visible part of the span to the defined max-width.
Is this possible?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any problems - http://jsfiddle.net/x6NHG/

Comment: i want it in one line and the overflow cut off

Comment: Gotta say, why would you use a span and then **NOT** display all of it? Seems like you should be using a different element.

Comment: @Paulie_D: what would you use?

Comment: @Thariama Since you haven't provided any HTML/CSS context it's hard to answer with any specificity but, in general, spans would be used to elements **within** another element. It really isn't logical to **not** display the whole width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the overflow to avoid expanding.

e.g. Adding:

`overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;`

Comment: is it possible without "display: block;" ?

Comment: the display property should be inline-block. It doesn't affect original behaviour of placement but allows to set width.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `whitespace: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden` on your span to force it all on one line and truncate the text.

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/JZYWg/

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the css of your `span`. This will make the text cut off

[**More info**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If I use `display: inline-block` - the span wraps at 300px or you can use `overflow: hidden` as suggested by others.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/U6R2A/

Comment: i don't want it to wrap, i want it in one line and the overflow cut off (invisible)

Comment: Ah, see @gaynorvader answer - that should be what you are after!